# Regex in dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column like that

```
COL1
PACK[30% /2 prod.(if fidelity)]
PACK[3.85 € /2 prod.(if fidelity)]
PACK[40% /2nd prod.]
PACK[3.5 € /2 prod.]
```

I want create other column as following according COL1

```
fidelity_perc fidelity_euro rem_perc  rem_eu
30           3,85           40        3,5
```

using regex.

For `PACK[40% /2nd prod.]` I did `(?<=PACK\[)\d+(?=%)` but it's also walk for `PACK[30% /2 prod.(if fidelity)]` and I don't want this.

Comment: Maybe you want `df['COL1'].str.extract(r'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][()]*]', expand=False)`? See https://regex101.com/r/3jROEh/2

Comment: @Wiktor Thank you, and I want to add contains "fidelity" in my regex for example how could I do ?

Comment: `df['fidelity_perc'] = df['COL1'].str.extract(r'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][()]*]', expand=False)`?

Comment: @Wiktor This is ok for PACK[40% /2nd prod.] but not for PACK[30% /2 prod.(if fidelity)], I have to speficy contains "fidelity"

Comment: @viktor, it's not ok for fidelity I am trying

Comment: the pattern is like PACK[30% /2 prod.(if fidelity)]  and I want to have 30 if I have fidelity in my column

Comment: `r'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][]*\bfidelity\b[^][]*]'`? See https://regex101.com/r/3jROEh/3. What should be the answer here? These two expressions together with `r'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][()]*]'`?

Comment: Oh, yes!! perfect and if it's contains a + coud I replace by 'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][]*\+\b[^][]*]' ?

Comment: Then you do not need the word boundaries. No idea if you really need them, so use `r'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][]*\+[^][]*]'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `PACK[40% /2nd prod.]`, you can use

```py
df['COL1'].str.extract(r'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][()]*]', expand=False)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jROEh/2).

To get the `PACK[30% /2 prod.(if fidelity)]`, you can use

```
df['COL1'].str.extract(r'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][]*fidelity[^][]*]', expand=False)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jROEh/4)

Similarly, if you need to only find a value if there is a `+` sign, just replace `fidelity` with `\+`:

```py
df['COL1'].str.extract(r'PACK\[(\d[\d.]*)%[^][]*\+[^][]*]', expand=False)
```

**Details**

- `PACK\[` - a literal `PACK[` string
- `(\d[\d.]*)` - Capturing group 1: a digit an then any zero or more digits or dots as many as possible
- `%` - a `%` sign
- `[^][]*` - any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` as many as possible
- `\+` - a plus
- `fidelity` - a `fidelity` substring
- `[^][]*` - any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` as many as possible
- `[^][()]*` - any zero or more chars other than `[`, `]`, `(` and `)` as many as possible
- `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Hello I have an other question !  if want to add "not contains +" how could I do?

Comment: @T.mum You add `+` into the negated character class.

Comment: what's the negated class?

Comment: @T.mum See [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).